# variable gets reset when getPixel is called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsbitmapimagerep

Well, the title is pretty self-explanatory. I have tested this code thoroughly, and what I have found is that the code is somehow resetting "y" when getPixel is called. It shouldn't be possible you'd think, because the method doesn't take a pointer, but somehow that is what's happening. If I remove the line of code that calls getPixel, the code completes, although obviously nothing useful is produced. If anyone can figure out what's going on here, I would be most appreciative. (getPixel is in NSBitmapImageRep, FYI)

```
NSInteger pixWide = theCAPTCHA.pixelsWide;
NSInteger pixHigh = theCAPTCHA.pixelsHigh;
for (NSInteger x = 0; x<pixWide;x++)
{
    for (NSInteger y = 0; y<pixHigh;y++)
    {
        unsigned int thePixel[3];
        [theCAPTCHA getPixel:(unsigned long *)thePixel atX:x y:y];
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            theColors[i+(y*3)+(x*pixHigh)] = thePixel[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thePixel is an unsigned int but passed in as unsigned long. The function might be overflowing your integer and changing y. Try declaring thePixel as unsigned long

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I don't understand why y was being effected though. Obviously I missed something in computer science... Is it because that the overflow was scribbling over y's value?

Comment: yes, it assumes it has 64-bits of space to write, but  in fact it only has 32. Thus it writes 32 extra bits into memory which happens (by coincidence) to overwite y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thePixel` is an unsigned int but passed in as unsigned long. The function might be overflowing your integer and changing `y`. Try declaring `thePixel` as `unsigned long`

In memory, the variables are just laid out one after another. The function `getPixel:at:y:` assumes it has 64 bits to write to in the input, because it takes an `unsigned long *`. However your own variable `thePixel` is an `unsigned int *` and writing an `unsigned long` to it will cause an overflow in memory

Comment: Thanks. I'm not even sure why I was typecasting it in this manner. I can find no line of code where I need thePixel to be an unsigned int... Ah well, a lesson for the future!